# Refresh the datasource on password rotation in SpringBoot Application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-boot-actuator

Can someone please guide me, how I can refresh the datasource whenever the password is rotated for the database.
Basically I don't want any manual step to refresh the datasource(*like calling any endpoint*). Rather than I can poll a file to see if DB credentials are rotated using FileWatcher service.
I have already read few solutions over stackoverflow regarding the same ask. But I couldn't able to implement it successfully.
*Since I am new to stackoverflow can't comment on others question to get solution clarified.*
Below is simple class for creating the connection pool.

@Configuration

@EnableTransactionManagement

public class JpaConfig {

```
@Value("${db.username}")
private String username;

@Value("${db.password}")
private String password;

@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);         
        factory.setPackagesToScan("com.example");
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", true);
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", true);
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "none");
        properties.put("hibernate.generate_statistics",  false);
        factory.setJpaProperties(properties);
        return factory;
}   
@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
  JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
  txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
  return txManager;
}   
private DataSource dataSource() {
    HikariConfig hikariConfig = new HikariConfig();
    hikariConfig.setJdbcUrl("db_connection_url");
    hikariConfig.setUsername(username);
    hikariConfig.setPassword(password);
    hikariConfig.setPoolName("test_pool");
    HikariDataSource hikariDataSource = new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig);
    return hikariDataSource;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Spring Cloud Bus". And whenever you change the datasource password configuration, your service can listen for this event so that it can create a new bean based on the new configuration.

Please look at this document
https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-bus

Comment: Can you please help me with sample example, which I can refer?

Comment: Please take a look at spring centralize configuration 
https://spring.io/guides/gs/centralized-configuration/

Your service will load config from a config server. If you change the config on server, it will notice your service through cloud bus.

Answer (score 0):

This repo has solution for this question : https://github.com/visa2learn/spring-cloud-vault-db-cred-rotation
I find it quite useful.
Just to make solution better read about **SecretLeaseContainer** :
Event-based container to request secrets from Vault and renew the associated Lease. Secrets can be rotated, depending on the requested *RequestedSecret.getMode()*

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).